# Change TestCafe RequestMock API response based on request body

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am using TestCafe Request Mock feature to mock API response as shown below.

```
export const deleteDocMock = (status = 200) =>
  RequestMock()
    .onRequestTo({
      url: /\/api\/my-api\/.*/,
      method: 'DELETE',
    })
    .respond({some response}, status, {
      'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
      'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS',
    });
```

I am able to filter the request based on the URL and Method type but not based on the request body.
Now i have a use case where the API response needs to be different for the same API request if the request body is different.
For example if the request body for the api is as shown below, the response body would change

```
{
id: 1
name: 'foo'
}
```

And if the request body is like shown below, the response would be again be different

```
{
id: 2
name: 'bar'
}
```

Is there any way to filter the request based on the request body so that the response can be changed accordingly with TestCafe?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a predicate function in your [`onRequestTo`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/requestmock/onrequestto.html#filter-with-a-predicate). I created a simple example to demonstrate it:

```js
import { RequestMock } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Fixture`;

const mock = RequestMock()
    .onRequestTo(request => {
        console.log(request); // The full request object

        return request.url.indexOf('google') > -1; // Here you can set your own rule
    })
    .respond((req, res) => {
        res.setBody('<html><body><h1>OK</h1></body></html>');
    });

test
    .requestHooks(mock)
    ('test', async t => {
        await t
            .navigateTo('https://google.com')
            .debug(); // Here we can see our mocked response
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to filter by a predicate.
https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/requestmock/onrequestto.html#select-requests-to-be-handled-by-the-hook

Other filters on this page have example for requestMock as well as requestLogger, but predicate have example just for requestLogger. Anyways, check if it works.

Comment: Thanks @saurabh-shrivastava for your reply. I had seen this documentation for filter by a predicate, but could not figure out the right way to use the same. Have you seen any sample usage of the same?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help guys. This really helped me. I am now able to filter my request based on the request body. I am comparing the API request body to my expected json body and mocking the response if the condition passes. My code is like this now. I am comparing the buffers since `request.body` is of the type `buffer`.

```
const mock = RequestMock()
.onRequestTo(
  request =>
    request.url.match(/api\/assets\/.*\/staged-document/) &&
    request.method === 'post' &&
    !Buffer.compare(request.body, Buffer.from({"assetId":1,"name":"file1.name"}, 'utf-8')),
)
.respond({some response}, status, {
  'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
  'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS',
});
```